# Converting a variable value to (return) array in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```js
var a = [10,20,30,40];
var b = [11,22,33,44];
var c = [40,30,20,10];

var d = ["a","b","c"];

var e = d[2];

console.log(e[0]);
```

How do I make javascript treat string value of variable e (i.e. string 'c') as name of array so e[0] would return 40 and not the character at position [0]. Thank you for your support and sorry if it's a dumb question.

Comment: OP - you need to put the three arrays into an object or use the window object (not advised). What you're asking for is a [dynamic variable name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117127/use-dynamic-variable-names-in-javascript).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of string put the reference of the array as the element.

```
var d = [a, b, c];
```

```js
var a = [10, 20, 30, 40];
var b = [11, 22, 33, 44];
var c = [40, 30, 20, 10];

var d = [a, b, c];

var e = d[2];

console.log(e[0]);
```

---

Another way is to use [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) method but I don't prefer that method.

Refer : [Why is using the JavaScript eval function a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea)

Answer (score 3):

You would need to use [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval):

```
var e = eval(d[2]);
```

However, the fact that you need to use `eval` usually means you've done something else wrong. You would most likely be better off with a single variable containing an array of arrays, instead of several variables each containing an array. [Pranav C Balan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38725959/772035) is one way to create an array of arrays from your individual arrays.

Comment: I don't think this results in what OP has asked for. OP wants e to equal 40.

Comment: @evolutionxbox He wants `e[0]` to be 40, because he wants `e` to be ` reference to `c`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this if your arrays are keys of an object:

```
var arrays = {
    a: [10, 20, 30, 40],
    b: [11, 22, 33, 44],
    c: [40, 30, 20, 10],
}

var d = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

var e = d[2];

console.log(arrays[e][0]); // Will output "40".
```

This avoids the use of `eval()` that is potentially unsafe!

**OR** If you really need that `a`, `b` and `c` be an variable instead of an object key, you can do as @pranav answer:

```
var d = [a, b, c];
```

This will create references for your original arrays, then you could do:

```
console.log(d[2][0]); // Will output "40" too!
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use double quotes.

`var d = [a,b,c]`

then

```
console.log(e[0][0]) will return the element you want
```

Answer (score 0):

In the way you want, you can do it with `this` keyword

```js
var a = [10,20,30,40];
var b = [11,22,33,44];
var c = [40,30,20,10];

var d = ["a","b","c"];

var e = this[d[2]];

console.log(e[0]);
```